# Android Emulator won't display xml file linked with Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

So I tried making my first android app with a few buttons and a textview and the buttons perform a simple task. However, the emulator doesn't seem to display the components, it just gives me a blank screen.

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Build;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

int counter;
Button add;
Button subtract;
TextView display;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    counter=0;
    add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    subtract = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

        }
    });

    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);

        }
    });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    return rootView;
}


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

Here is the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.example.helloworld.MainActivity.java" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Your total is 0"
    android:textSize="20dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bAdd"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Add one"
    android:textSize="20dp" >
</Button>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/bSub"
    android:layout_width="186dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Subtract one"
    android:textSize="20dp" >
    </Button>
```

Thanks ahead :)

Comment: Make sure the views are in the proper layout: `fragment_main.xml`, not in `activity_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

From your code, looks like all the components are in your fragment_main layout. delete the code i.e., method onCreateView (.....) on the top and paste the entire stuff in the bottom onCreateView like this. You cannot have 2 onCreateView methods defined in your java code.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
 counter=0;
    add = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
    subtract = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bSub);
    display = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);

    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            display.setText("Your total is " + counter);

        }
    });

    subtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter--;
            display.setText("Your total is" + counter);

        }
    });


    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

        return rootView;
    }
```